# How to connect local container to Docker Swarm remotely

Tags: windows, docker, remote-access, docker-swarm

I have Ubuntu 16 server with running docker containers in Swarm mode on it.
Server Docker version is `1.12.5, build 7392c3b`.

I want to create Docker container on local machine (or another Ubuntu server) and give this container access to Docker Swarm network on the fist server to be able to request nodes inside Swarm.

My local machine has Windows 10 OS.

**Is it possible to give access into Docker Swarm network to Docker remote container?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. If your local machine joins the swarm (`docker swarm join`) then it would be part of the swarm overlay network.